# Is it possible to make iPad show normal action sheet without popover?

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

When I want to show an action sheet in my app I show `UIAlertController` with preffered style `.ActionSheet`. However when running on iPad it is not shown as an action sheet but as a popover. And this is not what I need. I would like to still show normal action sheet. And I have a few questions regarding this:

1) Is there a way to force iPad show an action sheet?
2) If not, then maybe there's a library which does that?
3) If there's no such library and I have to write my own custom implementation of an action sheet then will Apple reject me for making iPad show it instead of a popover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't change this.
2. https://github.com/ianb821/IBActionSheet
3. If you want to implement custom implementation by your own then you can do it. Apple will not reject this.